# How to run spring batch application without spring boot maven plugin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Is it possible to run a spring batch application without spring boot maven plugin?

I need to run the application on another server and transferring a big jar (with spring dependencies) is time consuming. For this reason I want to compile and create a jar without spring dependencies included inside the jar and run it from command line.

Comment: You do realize that to run this application - spring dependencies are required to be there ? You will have to ensure that all reqired dependencies are present there with **correct** versions ?

Comment: In other words, you **require** spring dependencies in order to run the application.

Comment: Yes, I want to know how to run a spring application without adding spring dependencies into the jar. I do not want to create a big fat/ uber jar. I can add them in  the classpath later.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a simple JAR without spring boot dependencies, remove `spring-boot-plugin` from build.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  </plugin>
```

Above snippet should not be present in your `pom.xml`.
With this, fat/uber jar won't be created.

To run built jar:

```
java -cp MyJar.jar:lib/* com.somepackage.subpackage.Main
```

Where your libraries are contained in lib directory relative to current directory and `MyJar.jar` is the name of the jar built with maven.

Comment: If this answers your question, kindly accept the answer by clicking on tick mark.